# JAXB: Child Element Returning from WebServiceTemplate is null

Tags: java, spring, web-services, jaxb

I am using string-ws to create webservice client and fetching data from the webservice. I have used org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin to generate the java classes. Some of the classes are given below generated by this plugin:

GetLandingPageFAQ:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "getLandingPageFAQ", propOrder = {
    "faq"
})
public class GetLandingPageFAQ {

    protected FaqListInBean faq;

    public FaqListInBean getFaq() {
        return faq;
    }

    public void setFaq(FaqListInBean value) {
        this.faq = value;
    }
}
```

FaqListInBean:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "faqListInBean", propOrder = {
    "viewList",
    "localList",
    "numberOfContent"
})
public class FaqListInBean {

    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected List<String> viewList;
    @XmlElement(nillable = true)
    protected List<String> localList;
    protected int numberOfContent;

    public List<String> getViewList() {
        if (viewList == null) {
            viewList = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.viewList;
    }

    public List<String> getLocalList() {
        if (localList == null) {
            localList = new ArrayList<String>();
        }
        return this.localList;
    }

    public int getNumberOfContent() {
        return numberOfContent;
    }

    public void setNumberOfContent(int value) {
        this.numberOfContent = value;
    }    
}
```

GetLandingPageFAQResponse:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "getLandingPageFAQResponse", propOrder = {
    "faqListOutBean"
})
public class GetLandingPageFAQResponse {

    @XmlElement(name = "FaqListOutBean", namespace = "omitted")
    protected FaqListOutBean faqListOutBean;

    public FaqListOutBean getFaqListOutBean() {
        return faqListOutBean;
    }

    public void setFaqListOutBean(FaqListOutBean value) {
        this.faqListOutBean = value;
    }
}
```

The WSDL is:

```
<definitions xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="omitted" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" targetNamespace="omitted" name="MyService">
    <types>
        <xsd:schema>
            <xsd:import namespace="omitted" schemaLocation="http://url?xsd=1"/>
        </xsd:schema>
    </types>
    <message name="getLandingPageFAQ">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:getLandingPageFAQ"/>
    </message>
    <message name="getLandingPageFAQResponse">
        <part name="parameters" element="tns:getLandingPageFAQResponse"/>
    </message>
    <message name="WsException">
        <part name="fault" element="tns:WsException"/>
    </message>
    </message>
    <portType name="MyServiceImpl">
        <operation name="getLandingPageFAQ">
            <input message="tns:getLandingPageFAQ"/>
            <output message="tns:getLandingPageFAQResponse"/>
            <fault message="tns:WsException" name="WsException"/>
        </operation>
    </portType>
    <binding name="MyServiceImplPortBinding" type="tns:MyServiceImpl">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
        <operation name="getLandingPageFAQ">
            <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
            <input>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </input>
            <output>
                <soap:body use="literal"/>
            </output>
            <fault name="WsException">
                <soap:fault name="WsException" use="literal"/>
            </fault>
        </operation>
    </binding>
    <service name="MyService">
        <port name="MyServiceImplPort" binding="tns:MyServiceImplPortBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://url/MyService"/>
        </port>
    </service>
</definitions>
```

The xsd is:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:tns="omitted" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" version="1.0" targetNamespace="omitted">
    <xs:element name="WsException" type="tns:WsException"/>
    <xs:element name="FaqListInBean" type="tns:faqListInBean"/>
    <xs:element name="FaqListOutBean" type="tns:faqListOutBean"/>
    <xs:element name="getLandingPageFAQ" type="tns:getLandingPageFAQ"/>
    <xs:element name="getLandingPageFAQResponse" type="tns:getLandingPageFAQResponse"/>

    <xs:complexType name="faqListInBean">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="viewList" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="localList" type="xs:string" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="numberOfContent" type="xs:int"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="faqListOutBean">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="faqList" type="tns:simpleFAQOutBean" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="categoryList" type="tns:categoryOutBean" nillable="true" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            <xs:element name="numberOfContent" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="getLandingPageFAQ">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="faq" type="tns:faqListInBean" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="getLandingPageFAQResponse">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="tns:FaqListOutBean" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="WsException">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="message" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

I am generating the Java classes by hitting the URL directly and I don't have the xsd or the jaxb binding file added to my project. Here is how I am generating it:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.12.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>faq--api-service</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>generate</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                <generateDirectory>src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                <generatePackage>package</generatePackage>
                <removeOldOutput>true</removeOldOutput>
                <cleanPackageDirectories>true</cleanPackageDirectories>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>
                        <url>url</url>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
                <args>
                    <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
                </args>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                        <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.1</version>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

The ObjectFactory class is:

```
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementDecl;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRegistry;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;

@XmlRegistry
public class ObjectFactory {

    private final static QName _WsException_QNAME = new QName("omitted", "WsException");
    private final static QName _FaqListInBean_QNAME = new QName("omitted", "FaqListInBean");
    private final static QName _FaqListOutBean_QNAME = new QName("omitted", "FaqListOutBean");
    private final static QName _GetLandingPageFAQ_QNAME = new QName("omitted", "getLandingPageFAQ");
    private final static QName _GetLandingPageFAQResponse_QNAME = new QName("omitted", "getLandingPageFAQResponse");

    public ObjectFactory() {
    }

    public WsException createWsException() {
        return new WsException();
    }

    public FaqListInBean createFaqListInBean() {
        return new FaqListInBean();
    }

    public FaqListOutBean createFaqListOutBean() {
        return new FaqListOutBean();
    }

    public GetLandingPageFAQ createGetLandingPageFAQ() {
        return new GetLandingPageFAQ();
    }

    public GetLandingPageFAQResponse createGetLandingPageFAQResponse() {
        return new GetLandingPageFAQResponse();
    }


    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "omitted", name = "WsException")
    public JAXBElement<WsException> createWsException(WsException value) {
        return new JAXBElement<WsException>(_WsException_QNAME, WsException.class, null, value);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "omitted", name = "FaqListInBean")
    public JAXBElement<FaqListInBean> createFaqListInBean(FaqListInBean value) {
        return new JAXBElement<FaqListInBean>(_FaqListInBean_QNAME, FaqListInBean.class, null, value);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "omitted", name = "FaqListOutBean")
    public JAXBElement<FaqListOutBean> createFaqListOutBean(FaqListOutBean value) {
        return new JAXBElement<FaqListOutBean>(_FaqListOutBean_QNAME, FaqListOutBean.class, null, value);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "omitted", name = "getLandingPageFAQ")
    public JAXBElement<GetLandingPageFAQ> createGetLandingPageFAQ(GetLandingPageFAQ value) {
        return new JAXBElement<GetLandingPageFAQ>(_GetLandingPageFAQ_QNAME, GetLandingPageFAQ.class, null, value);
    }

    @XmlElementDecl(namespace = "omitted", name = "getLandingPageFAQResponse")
    public JAXBElement<GetLandingPageFAQResponse> createGetLandingPageFAQResponse(GetLandingPageFAQResponse value) {
        return new JAXBElement<GetLandingPageFAQResponse>(_GetLandingPageFAQResponse_QNAME, GetLandingPageFAQResponse.class, null, value);
    }
}
```

Now the client that I have written is:

```
public class FaqApiServiceClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    public FaqApiServiceClient() {
        try {
            String uri = getFaqUri();
            setDefaultUri(uri);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new ClientInstantiationException(ex);
        }
    }

    public GetLandingPageFAQResponse getLandingPageFAQResponse() {
        ObjectFactory objectFactory = new ObjectFactory();
        GetLandingPageFAQ faq = new GetLandingPageFAQ();
        FaqListInBean bean = objectFactory.createFaqListInBean();
        bean.getLocalList().add("en_US");
        faq.setFaq(bean);
        JAXBElement<GetLandingPageFAQ> request = new ObjectFactory().createGetLandingPageFAQ(faq);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        JAXBElement<GetLandingPageFAQResponse> response = (JAXBElement<GetLandingPageFAQResponse>) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(request);
        return response.getValue();
    }

    private String getUri() throws IOException {
        InputStream stream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("wsdl-url.properties");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(stream);
        return properties.getProperty("FaqAPIService.WSDL");
    }
}
```

Now the object `GetLandingPageFAQResponse` which is returing is not null but I cannot find the child objects `FaqListOutBean`. From SoapUI when I am executing the same operating with same input data I can see there is output. I am unable to find what is wrong. Any suggestion would be very helpful. I have followed the tutorial from here: [Consuming a SOAP web service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/).

### Update

If I don't use the `JAXBElement` to send the request and pass the `GetLandingPageFAQ` instance directly then I am getting:

```
org.springframework.ws.client.core.support.WebServiceGatewaySupport.getWebServiceTemplate()
marshalSendAndReceive
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.oxm.MarshallingFailureException: JAXB marshalling exception; nested exception is javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[com.sun.istack.internal.SAXException2: unable to marshal type "GetLandingPageFAQ" as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement annotation]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the namespace & endpoint of the webservice that I was consuming. I checked the code of the webservice and then the issue got fixed.